# Express, correct way to check the presence of a parameter in the body

Tags: node.js, express

Which is the correct way of checking the presence of a parameter in the body?

I'm using `if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('myParam')){...}` but i see that someone just write `if(req.body.myParam){...}` but this second option will return false if the param has a numeric value of 0, doesn't it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right.

if you want to check if the attribute exists so `hasOwnProperty` will do the job.

Using `req.body.myParam` will return false for any falsely such as `0`, `''`, `false`, `null` or `undefined`.

Also note that the dot notation and the `hasOwnProperty` method do no have the same behavior :

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

So it can be confusing, for example, run the above snippet :

```js
var o = new Object();

if (o.toString) {
  console.log('Dot notation can be confusing, inherited property example : ', o.__proto__.toString);
}

if (o.hasOwnProperty('toString')) {
  // nope
} else {
  console.log("that's why the hasOwnProperty method can be preferred");
}
```